# Is this an appropriate forum for web design implementation and troubleshooting questions?

Tags: support

I often have to troubleshoot cross-browser and cross-platform CSS and HTML issues; I've asked some questions of this type on StackOveflow, but some of the questions I've asked there bore no fruit, even after a few months. Is this forum a good place for CSS and HTML troubleshooting related questions?

Answer (score 3):

**No, it is not** In general, unless your programming question is about something like SEO, programming questions are off-topic. If you haven't gotten a response for your questions on stack overflow, I would use the bounty feature, or see if you can edit your question to make it more answerable. Also, take a look at this post: https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/a/883/6901

Comment: As 'pro webmasters' shouldn't we be helping others with CSS and HTML, these directly relate to being a web master. If we accept questions about apache2 and other server software that can be posted on server fault why not take CSS / HTML questions which are meant for websites. PHP on the other hand yes would be for SO along with other server side languages.